# HTTP 400 returned while accessing SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services Report Manager

Tags: iis, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a new SQL 2005 reporting services installation and it doesn't work.

Database access works fine.

I've setup a new IIS site, set it to run on port 90. It has the two virtual folders - Reports and ReportServer. I can access ReportServer just fine, but Reports (the report manager) throws HTTP 400 error.

I've changed the URL in rsreportserver.config and RSWebApplication.config but it still throws that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it on another server - the solution is simply to delete the IIS site which holds Report server and report manager, then create a new IIS site, configure IP and port mapping and recreate the virtual directories.

Answer (score 1):

Download a copy of [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp).  Check to make sure that your browser requests are what you think they are.  Watch each request, especially the one that generates the HTTP/400.  Does that request look good to you?  This will give you a base from which to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Does the reporting services configuration tool report anything awry? What is it logging in the event log on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Config tool says everything is fine.

Nothing is logged in the event log from reporting services.

In the reporting services trace log I can find only initialization items (setting default values for variables).

When I look into the IIS log, I can see that an anonymous request comes in from my IP addess to /Reports, it's rejected, then it comes back with Windows authentication and that's it. /Reports does not fire a request to /ReportServer, it does not redirect me to /Reports/Folder - I think that's what it should do, right?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I manager to solve it.

What I did is I deleted the IIS website, started with plain vanilla web site (listening to all IP addresses) and reporting services running on local admin and sa in the database.

Then, confirmed that it's working, I went step-by-step and:

- changed IP address
- changed port
- lowered local user rights
- lowered database rights

and after every step, everything was still working fine.

I don't know what was the issue exactly, but this helped.

I have another server that shows the same problems, I will start there by just deleting and recreating the website (I think that solved the problem) and will let you know.